# HARD PROBLEM: How to get ADC Sampling to Sync with POSIX timer?

Tags: c, embedded, signal-processing, embedded-linux

I'm working on a side project that involves comparing ADC samples from a Waveform generator to calculations from my embedded device (in C).

The device takes continuous samples from a waveform generator, with the following settings:

- Sine Wave (60 Hz)
- 2.1 Vpk-Vpk
- 1.25 Vdc offset

On my device, I have a sine function that calculates the exact same data:

```
    double sine_wave(double amplitude, int freq, double time, int phase_number,
         double offset) 
{
    double voltage;
    double rad = 2 * M_PI * freq * time;

    voltage = amplitude * sin(rad) + offset;

    return voltage;
}
```

1. Where FREQ = 60,
2. amplitude = 1.05
3. Offset = 1.25.

Time is the parameter to an abstracted sine function: stop_timer - start_timer.

Where it it is the time elapsed before and after a single ADC sample has been polled.

In my device handler, I am running (pseduo code)

```
while (1) {
   Find_zero_crossing_point(); /* 1.25 is the midpoint */
   if (ADC_get_sample() == zero_crossing && (Adc_sample is increasing)) { /* start timer at zero-crossing point */ 
   start_timer(); /* get timestamp of initial point so it can be compared throughout */ 
   while (1) {
      stop_timer();
          measured_data = ADC_get_sample();
          expected_data = abstracted_sine_wave((stop_timer - start_timer));
          compare_both_value(measured_data, expected_data);

   }
```

To get stop_timer and start_timer, I'm using the timespec struct. And calling it with clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &stop_timer);

Now the problem isn't the implementation. I'm able to get the values to match up for the most part. The issue is the the sampling rate is not uniform. And I believe this is due to the nature of running it inside a while loop.

After running this for about 30 seconds, or approximately 810,000 samples (30 x 27,000 samples), the little deviation adds up and the values deviate too much for it to serve the purpose of this project.

I was wondering if you have a solution where I can keep the timing in sync throughout the entirely of the device running this infinite loop?

Thanks!! (I've spent days trying to crack this but nothing is coming to mind)

Comment: Avoid "sloppy typing" such as `2 * M_PI * freq * time;` where you wildly mix integer and floating point types and get the correct type by luck, rather than intentionally. Change to `2.0` and `freq` should be type `double`.

Comment: As for timing, Linux isn't a RTOS, so all real-time sensitive code should be on the embedded device(s) aka microcontrollers.

Comment: If you are using iio to read your ADC, you can probably improve accuracy by using the hrtimer trigger.

Comment: @Lundin make sense. So running on RTOS is probably the only way around this. But to code in RTOS, it's bare metal and there's a lot you have to code from scratch?

Comment: @AlexandreBelloni I'm using IIO to call ADC. It's better than the ADC function but not enough to get perfect timing. Can you elaborate on hrtimer trigger?

Comment: Have a look at libiio and using triggered buffers. There is a thread describing that here: https://ez.analog.com/linux-software-drivers/f/q-a/87287/ad7266---how-to-use-the-buffer-and-trigger-with-libiio